# Sourcetree custom action to edit .gitignore file (mac)

Tags: git, macos, customization, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

My aim is to easily edit the .gitignore file corresponding to a particular git local repository (graphically).

I think it would be possible to add a custom action so when we right-click a repository line of the main SourceTree window, it would directly open a text editor with the corresponding repository's .gitignore file. **How to add that custom action?**

In fact, i'm surprised there's not already a simple way to do that.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Sorry, yes, and it's "How to add this custom action?". (edited my question)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Custom Action](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/02/08/custom-actions-more-power-to-you/), to achieve that.

Go to `SourceTree > Preferences > Custom Actions > Add ..`

For example, if you want to edit your .gitignore file using SublimeText on OSX you can use this settings:

> Script to run:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> $REPO/.gitignore
> ```